# How to get rid of the error message when evaluating a highly oscillatory numerical integral?

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I have a simple numerical integral with a highly oscillatory integrand:

```
In[256]:= Integrate[Exp[-x^2] Cos[100 x], {x, -10, 10}] // N

Out[256]= 5.11136*10^-46 + 0. I
```

Using numerical integration, I used the method `"LevinRule"` and increased the `WorkingPrecision` to `50`. I got the right result, but it came with an error message:

```
In[273]:= NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2] Cos[100 x], {x, -10, 10}, 
  Method -> {"LevinRule"}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]

Out[273]= 5.1113608752199056046419863980883842786372578322323*10^-46
```

The error message says that the integral failed to converge, which makes me worry if I don't know the exact answer in advance.

```
During evaluation of In[273]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too
slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0,
highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>

During evaluation of In[273]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to
prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near
{x} = {0.06347548783822353791148881980667872878998059126103862089665838701205185579592695769871303841009927124}.
NIntegrate obtained 5.111360875219905604641986398088384278637257832232254321100441868877978318265582017097113446297596528`100.*^-46
and 2.115650450746176575259758050321352748848126918694539847444939975975907083592875723586821709970659407`100.*^-59
for the integral and error estimates. >>
```

How do I get rid of this error message, without suppressing it?

Comment: Have you ever heard about `Quiet`?

Comment: @mmal What f I don't know the exact answer? I suppose suppress the error message is dangeous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try setting the [`AccuracyGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AccuracyGoal.html) lower than `WorkingPrecision`, which yields the correct result without a reported warning.

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2] Cos[100 x], {x, -10, 10}, 
 Method -> {"LevinRule"}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 35]
```

> 5.1113608752199120138254477520179596033660767259737*10^-46

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2] Cos[100 x], {x, -10, 10}, 
 Method -> {"LevinRule"}, WorkingPrecision -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> 90]
```

> 5.11136087521990299641307044175882379310640009556142432636206474874790\
>   3858004996545055056958734154112*10^-46

[Reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ControllingThePrecisionOfResults.html).

> When you give a setting for `WorkingPrecision`, this typically defines an upper limit on the precision of the results from a computation. But within this constraint you can tell the Wolfram Language how much precision and accuracy you want it to try to get.

In a highly oscillatory function, the last few digits of precision may not converge and/or take extended time.

Comment: Can you explain why this works and why the previous code report an error? The error says `failed to converge to prescribed accuracy` I assume this means that the `AccuracyGoal` set by default is very very high(even higher than 35 and 90?)...

Comment: The links says `AccuracyGoal->Automatic normally yields an accuracy goal equal to half the setting for WorkingPrecision. `. I suppose when I unspecify the AccuracyGoal, it is set to `25`, but why it can't converge but can when it set explicitly to `35`

Comment: I didn't find it explicitly says only true for `NDSolve`

Comment: We are not talking about the same link... You are right, maybe the default value in `NIntegrate` is the `WorkingPrecision`.

Comment: The link in your first sentence...Click on details, it doesn't says this is true only for NDSolve..

Comment: I see. The key word is normally. It seems `NIntegrate` is using something higher than 35 for a `WorkingPrecision` of 50

Comment: I'm going to delete all my comments to clean this up ... thank you for the accept

Comment: @anoffercan'trefuse The default setting for `AccuracyGoal` for `NIntegrate` is `Infinity`.  By setting it to `35`, `NIntegrate` is accepting the estimate it derived because the error estimate is less than `10^-35`, which means that it is asserting that the value of the integral is between `5 * 10^-46 - 10^-35` and `5 * 10^-46 + 10^-35`, that is, the result does not even confirm the sign of the result.

Answer (score 12):

> The shortest and best way between two truths of the real domain often passes through the imaginary one.
>
> — Jacques Hadamard

By taking a *complex* path, I get the answer without any complaints from *Mathematica*.

```
parabolic[a_, x_] = Simplify[InterpolatingPolynomial[{{-10, 0}, {0, a}, {10, 0}}, x]]

With[{a = 1}, 
     Re[NIntegrate[With[{x = x + I parabolic[a, x]}, 
                        Exp[-x^2 + 100 I x]] (1 + I Derivative[0, 1][parabolic][a, x]),
                   {x, -10, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]]]
   5.1113608752199029964*10^-46
```

If you want further reading, see [this](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=tAG5TLGNw8oC&pg=PA20) or [this](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=c5gLFYcKHSgC&pg=PA157).

Comment: This is a very smart way!

Comment: Pfft! Using brute force is [better](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222500)!

Comment: @Anton, sometimes ;D

Answer (score 4):

> When in doubt, use brute force.
>
> -- Ken Thompson

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2] Cos[100 x], {x, -10, 10}, 
  Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, "SingularityHandler" -> None}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 100, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 90, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
]

(* {100.201, 
 5.111360875219902996413070441758823793106400095561424326362063281173449212599595171095728154857298543*10^-46} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another brute-force approach, but quick:

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2] Cos[100 x], 
   Evaluate@Flatten@{x, Range[-10., 10, 2 Pi/100], 10.}, 
   Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 31}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 25, WorkingPrecision -> 100] // 
  N[#, 50] & // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.231645, 5.1113608752199029964130704417588237931064000955614*10^-46}  *)
```