# NIntegrate Oscillating kernel

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, trigonometry

I have a finite highly oscillating integral of the type:

```
NIntegrate[x^2 Exp[I f[x] s] , {x, 0, 1}]
```

where `f` is a simple function like `Log[1 + x]/x`. This integral becomes highly oscillatory for large `s` and there are numerical errors showing up. Mathematica's standard numerical integration methods are only for kernels `Exp[I x s]`.

How do I deal with this? Do I need to manually implement a method?
I think this should be possible because the oscillating function is still trigonometric and `f` varies more slowly than `x`.

Comment: Try this:https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html

Comment: What are the magnitudes of the "large `s`"? E.g $s \in [10,100]$ or $s \in [10^5,10^6]$ ?

Comment: @AntonAntonov maybe up to 10^{4,5,6,7} but I dunno for sure depends on what I'll do later with this integral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two ways, a simple change of variables and an assist to the Levin Rule.

***Change of variables***

```
Block[{f, s},
 integrand = ComplexExpand[
    x^2 Exp[I f[x] s], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}
    ] Dt[x];
 f[x_] := Log[1 + x]/x;
 s = 10^7;
 NIntegrate[integrand /. x -> 1/u /. Dt[u] -> 1, {u, Infinity, 1}]
 ]

(*  -2.48219*10^-9 + 5.17734*10^-7 I  *)
```

***Explicit Levin Rule***

For details on the Levin Rule, see [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#32844337):

```
Block[{f, s},
 li = NIntegrate`LevinIntegrandReduce[x^2 Exp[I f[x] s], x];
 f[x_] := Log[1 + x]/x;
 s = 10^7;
 NIntegrate[li, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "LevinRule"]
 ]

(*  -2.48219*10^-9 + 5.17734*10^-7 I  *)
```

Check consistency:

```
Block[{f, s},
 li = NIntegrate`LevinIntegrandReduce[x^2 Exp[I f[x] s], x];
 f[x_] := Log[1 + x]/x;
 s = 10^7;
 {NIntegrate[li, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "LevinRule"],
  NIntegrate[li, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "LevinRule", 
   WorkingPrecision -> 32],
  NIntegrate[li, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> {"LevinRule", "Points" -> 11}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 24],
  NIntegrate[li, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> {"LevinRule", "Points" -> 21}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 24]}
 ]
(*
{-2.48219*10^-9 + 5.17734*10^-7 I,
 -2.4821858856455486537866819639768*10^-9 + 
   5.1773393974054904734746810429446*10^-7 I, 
 -2.48218588564554865378666*10^-9 + 
   5.17733939740549047347468*10^-7 I,
 -2.48218588564554865378660*10^-9 +
   5.17733939740549047347468*10^-7 I}
*)
```

Answer (score 8):

## Asymptotics (integration by parts)

Since the integrand is highly oscillatory for large $s$, we can obtain an asymptotic expression by performing integration by parts.

Observe that

$$
\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 x^2 \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} f(x) s} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\mathrm{i} f'(x) s} \,\mathrm{d}\left( \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} f(x) s} \right) \\
&= \left[ \frac{x^2 \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} f(x) s}}{\mathrm{i} f'(x) s} \right]_0^1 - \int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} f(x) s} \,\mathrm{d} \left( \frac{x^2}{\mathrm{i} f'(x) s} \right).
\end{align}
$$

The first term (boundary term) is already small, since it is of order $1/s$. Assuming $f$ is sufficiently well behaved, the second term is even smaller, since we have a highly oscillatory integrand of order $1/s$ (I would expect the second term to be of order $1/s^2$).

So we merely need to evaluate the boundary term:

```
f[x_] := Log[1 + x] / x
boundaryTerm[s_][x_] := x^2 Exp[I f[x] s] / (I f'[x] s);
result = boundaryTerm[s][1] - Limit[boundaryTerm[s][x], x -> 0]
```

> $$-\frac{\mathrm{i} \, 2^{\mathrm{i} s}}{s (1/2 - \log 2)} $$

```
Table[{s, result // N}, {s, 10^Range[4, 7]}] // TableForm
```

| $s$ | `result` |
| --- | --- |
| $10^4$ | $-0.000465659 + 0.00022631 \,\mathrm{i}$ |
| $10^5$ | $0.0000508565 + 9.70392 \cdot 10^{-6} \,\mathrm{i}$ |
| $10^6$ | $4.92323 \cdot 10^{-6} + 1.60227 \cdot 10^{-6} \,\mathrm{i}$ |
| $10^7$ | $-2.48291 \cdot 10^{-9} + 5.17734 \cdot 10^{-7} \,\mathrm{i}$ |

This is consistent with Michael E2's result.

### Addendum: more terms

We can obtain a full asymptotic expansion by performing integration by parts iteratively. We get
$$
\int_0^1 x^2 \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} f(x) s} \,\mathrm{d}x =
  \frac{A_1}{s} + \frac{A_2}{s^2} + \frac{A_3}{s^3} + \text{etc.},
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
  T_1 (x) &= \frac{x^2}{\mathrm{i} f'(x)}, \\
  T_n (x) &= \frac{T_{n-1}' (x)}{\mathrm{i} f'(x)},
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
A_n = (-1)^{n + 1} \left[ T_n (x) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} f(x) s} \right]_0^1.
$$

In the case of $s = 10^7$, taking 6 terms allows us to achieve all of the decimal places in Michael E2's `WorkingPrecision -> 32` check:

```
f[x_] := Log[1 + x] / x

t[1] = x^2 / (I f'[x]);
t[n_] := t[n] = D[t[n - 1], x] / (I f'[x]);

a[n_] := a[n] =
  (-1)^(n + 1) * Subtract[
    Limit[t[n] Exp[I f[x] s], x -> 1],
    Limit[t[n] Exp[I f[x] s], x -> 0]
  ];

asympTerm[n_] := a[n] / s^n;
```

```
nMax = 6;
asympSum = Sum[asympTerm[n], {n, nMax}];
asympSum /. {s -> 10^7} // N[#, 34] &
(*
  -2.4821858856455486537866819639768*10^-9
  +5.177339397405490473474681042944648*10^-7 I
*)

(* Check size of omitted term *)
asympTerm[nMax + 1] /. {s -> 10^7} // N
(*
  4.98211*10^-47 - 4.15958*10^-42 I
*)
```

**WARNING.** This is an *asymptotic* expansion, NOT a convergent expansion. At some point the terms will start getting larger, and the series will NOT converge. Always check the size of the first omitted term.

Comment: Cool. This is a better problem than I first thought when I saw the OP.

Comment: Very nice. It's a pity `AsymptoticIntegrate[]` does not work on the OP's problem...

Answer (score 5):

Once again demonstrating the power of [Hadamard's maxim](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120601), let us use a parabolic contour to evaluate this oscillatory integral:

```
parabolic[a_, x_] = Simplify[InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, 0}, {1/2, -a}, {1, 0}}, x]];

With[{s = 1*^7, a = 1/2}, 
     NIntegrate[With[{x = x + I parabolic[a, x]}, 
                     x^2 Exp[I Log[1 + x]/x s]]
                (1 + I Derivative[0, 1][parabolic][a, x]), {x, 0, 1}, 
                MaxRecursion -> 12, WorkingPrecision -> 25]]
   -2.4821858856388198658695*10^-9 + 5.177339397405635636628810*10^-7 I
```

Comment: Nice. One can use a polygonal path as well: `NIntegrate[x^2 Exp[I Log[1 + x]/x 10^7], {x, 0, 1/2 - I/2, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 25, MaxRecursion -> 12]`

Comment: Yes, that works nicely too, @Michael. A serious effort (and a more complicated integrand) would probably have to delve into determining "steepest descent contours", but the simple approaches you and I give are already good enough for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the method "LocalAdaptive", the integration routine of MMA will put more sample points in the region where the integrand oscillates strongly. Here is an example:

```
NIntegrate[x^2 Exp[I Log[1 + x]/x 10000000], {x, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

This gives:

```
9.90376*10^-8 + 0.0000697064 I
```

Comment: I wouldn't trust these results.Even `NIntegrate[x^2 Exp[I Log[1 + x]/x 10000000], {x, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> "DoubleExponentialOscillatory", WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
 MaxRecursion -> 10000]` error is about `0.035` !.