# Levin Rule Integrate Power of Oscillating Function

Tags: numerical-integration, trigonometry

I want to numerically integrate a function of the form:

```
    NIntegrate[Exp[I a x] x^-n (1+Exp[I b x])^n,{x,1,10^4}, 
    Method -> {"LevinRule", "LevinFunctions" -> {"TrigRelated"}}]
```

BTW, Mathematica understands this better using Euler's formula `exp = cos + i sin` .

The Levin Rule wants a explicit oscillating kernel like `Exp[I 1/50 x]` . The obvious solution would be to expand the bracket using the binomial theorem and then there would be contributions like `Exp[I (a+l b) x]`  - oscillations with well defined frequency. But then I need to compute N integrals instead of 1 and there will be cancellations.
Is there a smarter way of telling the Levin Rule what to do than the Binomial expansion?

Comment: With: `g[a_, b_, n_, Z_] := 
 NIntegrate[Exp[I a x] x^-n (1 + Exp[I b x])^n, {x, 1, Z}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 30]; f[1/500, 1/500, 10, 10^4]` standard method works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatic Levin-rule reduction of the integrand picks $e^{iax}$ for the kernel and $e^{-ibx}/x^n$ for the amplitude, which fails to capture the whole oscillatory component.  You can rescue the Levin rule manually.  See [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#32844337) for details.

We need to construct a basis $\{w_j\}$, the Levin "kernel," that satisfies a homogeneous linear ODE
$$w_j'(x)=\sum_k A_{j,k}(x) w_k(x) \,.$$
For this problem, we may pick for the kernel the following:
$$w_j(x) = e^{iax}\left(1+e^{ibx}\right)^j\,, \quad j=0,\dots,n \,.$$
A simple calculation (luckily) shows
$$w_j'(x)=i a \, w_j(x)+i b j \left(w_j(x)-w_{j-1}(x)\right) \,,$$
which is programmatically valid for $j=0$ since $w_{j-1}$ is multiplied by $j$.

In the code below, only the kernel `levinK[n]` and the differential matrix $A$ `levinDM[n]` are needed to implement the Levin rule in `NIntegrate`. The others were written for checking the ODE above.  While `levinDM[]` uses `levinODE[]` and `levinVARS[]`, it could directly compute the matrix.

```
ClearAll[levinODE, levinICS];
levinODE[n_] := 
  Table[w[j]'[x] == I*a*w[j][x] + I*b*j*(w[j][x] - w[j - 1][x]), {j, 0, n}];
levinICS[n_] := Table[w[j][0] == 2^j, {j, 0, n}];
levinVARS[n_] := Array[w, n + 1, 0];
levinK[n_] := Table[Exp[I a x] (1 + Exp[I b x])^j, {j, 0, n}];
levinDM[n_] := CoefficientArrays[
     levinODE[n][[All, -1]],
     Through[levinVARS[n][x]]
     ][[2]]; (* Part 2 are the coefficients of the linear part *)
```

We have to specify the `"Amplitude"`, or `NIntegrate` will choose $w_0(x)$ for determining it instead of $w_n(x)$.

```
Block[{n = 4, a = 3, b = 4},
 NIntegrate[Exp[I a x] x^-n (1 + Exp[I b x])^n, {x, 1, 10^4}, 
  Method -> {"LevinRule"
    , "AdditiveTerm" -> 0
    , "Amplitude" -> SparseArray[{{n + 1} -> x^-n}, {n + 1}]
    , "Kernel" -> levinK[n]
    , "DifferentialMatrix" -> levinDM[n]
    , "Points" -> 20 + 10 n (* for a=3, b=4, n up to 8 or higher *)
    }]
 ]

(*  -0.01205 + 0.0929632 I  *)
```

The number of collocation `"Points"` needed depends on how oscillatory the integrand is (`a` and `b`) and the dimension of the Levin system (`n`).  I don't know off-hand a formula for it.  For `a` and `b` on the order of $10^{-3}$, the formula `5 + 5 n` works for small `n`.

Answer (score 2):

I thought it was cool how easy it was to do the Levin rule by hand, but there's an easier way.  [@J.M.'s advice for the OP's previous oscillatory integral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/237403/4999) applies here, too. A complex integration path can dampen the oscillations, something like `{x, 1, 1 + 2I, 10^4 + 2I, 10^4}`.  It's considerably faster than the Levin rule.  Since the integrand is analytic in a simply connected, complex neighborhood of `1 <= x <= 10^4` (for example, `Re[x] >= 0`), a high-order Gauss rule will be beneficial.

```
Block[{n = 4, a = 3, b = 4},
 NIntegrate[
  Exp[I a x] x^-n (1 + Exp[I b x])^n,
  {x, 1, 1 + 2 I, 10^4 + 2 I, 10^4}, 
  Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 21}]
 ]

(*  -0.01205 + 0.0929632 I  *)
```